# Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number

Tags: javascript, blockchain

I keep getting this bug : `BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number` when i want to call the function greet() from the following smart contract:

```
contract Greeter {

string greeting;

function Greeter(string _greeting) public {
greeting = _greeting;
}

function greet() constant returns (string) {
return greeting;
}
}
```

Here is the script:

```
var contractAddress = process.argv[2];
//var contractAddress = '0x21967ce2eb8c5fa2e9bac524e83f116c0fe989ca;
var contractInstance = GreeterContract.at(contractAddress);

contractInstance.greet.call().then(function(result) {
console.log('contract greeter: '+result);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?